# where should I start learning optimization theory?

Tags: optimization, reference-request, convex-optimization

I want to start learning some optimization theory (mainly to get into ML in the future but I'm also just very interested in mathematics that intersects heavily with engineering) and I would like to get some recommendations to start tackling the subject. I found two books: Bierlaire's Optimization book and Convex Optimization by Boyd and Vandenberghe but the former seems to lack convex optimization which I've heard is quite foundational and the latter seems to target more practitioners of optimization algorithm where I want to get into theory to understand exactly why the algorithms work and both mention that they target engineers in their preface and I'm not sure if that's a good or a bad thing. So are there any other introductory references to the subject that target mathematicians which I'm missing?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are looking for, but a standard text for finite dimensional convex analysis is Rockafellar's eponymous book.

Comment: Hi: check out luenberger's book. I don't know how it compares to boyd or bierlaire but I like it. The title is "optimization by vector space methods". He also has a second one ( I think it's called linear programming ? ) but I don't have that one.